# How did Adam Monroe survive eclipses?

Tags: powers, heroes

On the TV show *Heroes*, Adam Monroe (alias Takezo Kensei) possessed the power of rapid cellular regeneration. Like Claire Bennet, he was capable of healing nearly instantaneously, even recovering from otherwise lethal injuries. However, unlike her, he had lived long past his regular lifespan, and his power was the only thing holding him together. When it was removed, he crumbled to dust.

We see, though, that the eclipses take away the powers of existing heroes. The powers of people around the world were suppressed by the second eclipse, including Claire’s ability to regenerate.

In particular, the first eclipse, described as “global” by Mohinder Suresh, empowered people around the world. How was Adam, who had lived for hundreds of years, able to survive the solar eclipses he must have experienced, which should have robbed him of his powers (and by extension his life)?

Comment: Surely avoiding total eclipses of the sun isn't especially difficult. They're [easy to track](http://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/list.html) and incredibly rare.

Comment: @Valorum - The behavior of the eclipses in *Heroes* seems a bit odd. In *Genesis*, Mohinder says that the eclipse is somehow “global,” and indeed the eclipses shown in the show somehow seem to be seen around the world.

Comment: Well that's just bad science. And possibly worthy of its own question.

Comment: @Valorum - Regardless, the point is that it would *seem* that Monroe should have been affected at least by the first eclipse, the one that empowered the main cast. But maybe there is some explanation.

Comment: Ah. A very brief scan of the wiki suggests that it *is* a global event but it's not actually an eclipse by the moon. http://heroeswiki.com/Eclipse. Also, the writers are well aware that it makes no sense but ho-hum. I've noticed also that several characters don't seem to lose their powers but simply have them diminished (one character stops time during an eclipse, another is able to turn scaly(?)). Perhaps Adam was similar and simply didn't have his powers completely removed?

Comment: Just a quick aside:  Claire at least didn't get her powers during the first eclipse.  She survived a fire as a baby because of her regeneration ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the eclipse in "Genesis" functions the same way as the one in the Season 3 two-parter "The Eclipse", I guess there are two possibilities:

### Adam Monroe was somehow not reachable by the eclipse's effects

At the time of the "Genesis" eclipse, Adam was locked up in a windowless Primatech prison. If this put him out of reach of the eclipse's effects (perhaps he was too deep for some sort of solar-moonbeam radiation to reach him), then he would be unaffected.

### He lost his immortality without being dessicated and recovered

We see in "The Eclipse" that Sylar gets his neck sliced open, killing him. Then when the titular eclipse passes, is regeneration kicks in and he makes a full recovery. It's possible that the first eclipse either made him age normally or disabled, but not dessicated him such that he made a full recovery.

This would likely mean that when Arthur Petrelli took away his power, either the process was so intense that it dessicated him (in such a way that the less intense eclipse did not) or he used a second power to kill him after he sucked out Adam's regeneration power.

Unfortunately, we don't know for certain what happened since Adam's relation to the first eclipse was never explored.

Comment: On the second idea, while it didn't happen during an eclipse, Claire was killed once, dead for hours, and then regenerated when an obstruction was removed from the injury

Comment: @Izkata True, and the same with Sylar too when he had a glass shard in his head that eventually melted in a fire. Claire also had her powers permanently removed in *Heroes Reborn*, although she was still in her 20s when that happened, so it's not as surprising that there weren't too terrible of effects.

Comment: @Thunderforge - “weren’t too terrible of effects”…didn’t she *die*?

Comment: @Adamant I was trying to say that she didn't dessicate and crumble into ash as Adam did. I could have phrased that better!